# C# DISCORD.NET RemoveReactionAsync returning NullException

Tags: c#, discord, null, bots

I am trying to code a C# bot which remove a specific reaction EMOJI from a specific user on a specific message when the user is reacting on the message.

Here is my code :

```
private async Task reactionadded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> message, Cacheable<IMessageChannel, ulong> message2, SocketReaction sr)
{
    try
    {
        
        if (!(sr.User.GetValueOrDefault() as SocketUser).IsBot)
        {
            await message.Value.RemoveReactionAsync((IEmote)sr.Emote, sr.UserId);
            return;
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    }

}
```

At the moment, I am facing a problem with "RemoveReactionAsync", which is always returning a null exception when the message have been posted BEFORE I started the bot ( even if it have multiple emoji reaction, it will never find anything and return null causing a crash ). If I start the bot, post a message, with emoji on it, and the user click on the emoji, It will detect the emoji, and delete it as intended.

How can I use "RemoveReactionAsync" on older messages?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue some time ago. What fixed it for me was using `message.GetOrDownloadAsync().Result` instead of `message.Value`.

I hope it works for your problem as well:

```cs
private async Task reactionadded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> message, Cacheable<IMessageChannel, ulong> message2, SocketReaction sr)
{
    try
    {
        if (!(sr.User.GetValueOrDefault() as SocketUser).IsBot)
        {
            await message.GetOrDownloadAsync().Result.RemoveReactionAsync((IEmote)sr.Emote, sr.UserId);
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```